# Why =! seems a legit condition in php?

Tags: php

I just experienced a sort of bug while coding in Php: 
I was writing some condition like this:

```
if($showPrice != 0){
    $worksheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowCount.':F'.$rowCount);
    $worksheet->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, 'Total Weight');
    $worksheet->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $totalWeight);
}else{
    $worksheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowCount.':D'.$rowCount);
    $worksheet->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, 'Total Weight');
    $worksheet->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $totalWeight);
}
```

I noticed that instead of writing **!=** as I should, I was wrongly writing **=!** without getting any error.

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: `$showPrice =! 0` means to negate `0` and assign the result (`true`) to `$showPrice`. This results in the `if` condition always succeeding.

Comment: It probably becomes an assignment of the negative. `$x = !0`

Comment: ... condition always succeeding AND destroying the value in `$showPrice`

Comment: Related: https://www.exakat.io/weird-operators-in-php/ (Do not take anything in that article seriously!)

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote this, maybe can be trivial for an experienced programmer but not for a noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't find any bug in PHP. You found a bug in your program and in your knowledge about the PHP.

`$x =! 0` is, in fact, `$x = !0`.

`!` is the [logical `NOT` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).
`0` is [evaluated as `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in boolean context, consequently `!0` is `TRUE`.

`$x = ...` is a regular [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). As any assignment, it does two things:

- stores the value of the right-hand side expression into the left-hand side variable; here the expression is `!0` that, as explained above, is evaluated to `TRUE`;
- the value of the entire expression (`$x = !0`) is the value of `$x` after the assignment (`TRUE` as described).

When the assignment it is used as a statement, its value is discarded. When it is used as a condition (in a `for`, `while`, `if`, `switch` statement), its value is used to control the execution of the code.

Here, `if($showPrice =! 0)` always takes the `if` branch (and never the `else` branch) because the value of the `$showPrice = !0` expression is always `TRUE` as explained above.
More, the value of `$showPrice` also becomes `TRUE` after this statement is evaluated.

Two bugs in a single line of code.

From the PHP's point of view the code is perfectly valid and, even if it is unusual, maybe it represents the programmer's intention. The interpreter doesn't have any reason to complain about it. It can be, however, detected and flagged as a possible error by static code analysis tools and some PHP IDEs.

Comment: this is very c-ish :) 
of course i wasn't supposing the bug was in php